# How to re-order and fix breaks in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to r and trying to make a grouped barplot using ggplot2. I have gotten the plot made but am having issues re-ordering the data, as well as formatting the aesthetics graph.

The code I have used is:

```
# ggplot2 for bar graphs by time and treatment 

df<-read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
attach(df)
install.packages("ggplot2") # install ggplot2 package
require(ggplot2) # load package 
Treatment<-c(TreatID)
Treatment<-as.factor(Treatment)
Year<- as.factor(Year)

# year and treatment 
x<-sd(PF) # 12.98009
x<- PF
std <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)) #calculation of standard error
se<- std(x) # .2420988
se<-(0.2420988)


p<-ggplot(df, aes(x= Year, y= PF, fill= TreatID), scale_colour_grey) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat= "identity") + ggtitle("Percent Cover Perennial Forbs by Treatment")  + scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2015), labels=c("SMCU", "SMCS", "SMBU", "SMBS", "SMPS", "SMLS")) + ylab("% Cover Perennial Forbs") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= PF - se, ymax = PF + se), width= .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) # add error bars 
p + ylab("% Cover Perennial Forbs")
(p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)) #makes bars grey
(p = p + theme_bw()) #changes chart background to white
```

There is a large gap between 2011 and 2015 which I want removed, and the TreatID's need to be rearranged so that "SMCU" is first, followed by "SMCS", "SMBU", "SMBS", "SMLS" and then "SMPS".

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the gap, make sure Year is being treated as a factor.  And, to change the order of the treatments, reorder the factor.

```
## Some sample data
dat <- data.frame(Year=factor(rep(c(2009:2011, 2015), each=6)),
                  TreatID=factor(rep(c("SMCU", "SMCS", "SMBU", "SMBS", "SMPS", "SMLS"), 4)),
                  PF=runif(4*6))


## Reorder your TreatID levels
dat$TreatID <- factor(dat$TreatID, levels=c("SMCU", "SMCS", "SMBU", "SMBS", "SMLS", "SMPS"))
se <- 0.242

## Make sure Year is a factor so there is no gap
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=as.factor(Year), y= PF, fill= TreatID), scale_colour_grey) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Percent Cover Perennial Forbs by Treatment")  +
  ylab("% Cover Perennial Forbs") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= PF - se, ymax = PF + se), width= .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) +
  theme_bw()
p
```

[image]